# creation of different diagram view on double click

Tags: eclipse-sirius

In my model i have containers and they have n number of sub containers.So in my diagram view it is difficult for the user to view multiple sub containers created inside the container.So i want to create a multi layered diagram view such that instead viewing the containers and sub containers in the single diagram view i want to create diagram view for each container such that i can view sub containers in the different diagram view on double click on the container and it should have the relationship between different containers and sub containers even if it is present in the different diagram view .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DoubleClick tool for your mapping Container and then create a navigation operation with the checkbox "Create if non existent" checked.
[image: Screenshot of an example]

You can have a look at the [Dart Designer project on Github](https://github.com/dartdesigner/Dart-Designer/tree/master/bundles/org.obeonetwork.dsl.dart.design). In the odesign file, look for the navigation section of the "Explorer Diagram". This diagram represent a file system and you can click on folders to see what's inside.